# I am running this javascript code but it is giving me an.. error please tell me what is wrong because I think the code is correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
let marks_of_students = [100,100,40]

function FindGrade(marks) {

let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0;i <= marks.length; i++) {
  sum += marks[i];
  console.log(sum);
}
return sum;
}
console.log(FindGrade(marks_of_students));
```

I don't know why I'm seeing this NaN printing along side the sum. Someone please help what did I do wrong?

Comment: Post the code in the question here instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop over the mark_of_students array with a condition `i <= marks.length` which means the loop will try to find `marks[3]` in the last iteration which doesn't exist. You need to change the condition to `i < marks.length` to get the desired result.

```js
let marks_of_students = [100, 100, 40]

function FindGrade(marks) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
        sum += marks[i]
    }

    return sum
}


console.log(FindGrade(marks_of_students))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert a object into a integer by command parseInt(object) to sum.

Im javascript concatenates,  NaN is not a number;

Try to do this:

parseInt("1") + parseInt("1")

instead of 1 + 1